# Meteor embedded documents reactivity

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, spacebars

I have a bootstrap modal that will display info about a parent document. The modal then has `next/prev` buttons that can rotate around a list of parent documents and reactively change the info displayed on the modal. It does this by simply changing a ReactiveVar of the current parent's onClick of next/prev. This works like a charm.

My problem is that each parent shows some child data as well. The child data is an array of embedded documents. And each document's property has some HTML inputs. I'm trying to pre-populate the values of the html inputs. However, I'm finding this does not work. `id` and `foo` are properties on the child document(s).

A call to {{parent}} is a `Helper` method that returns the current `parent` from MiniMongo. This seems to work fine as the parent's metadata changes reactively.

```
{{#each parent.childrenArray}}
    <input type="text" id="{{id}}" value="{{foo}}">
{{/each}}
```

So the issue is that the HTML value does not change. Clicking `next` will still show the old child's value. I understand there's no reactivity for embedded documents and I'm sure this is the problem. Strangely, upon inspecting, I am in fact seeing the `input's` `id` being changed though. Does anybody know the solution to this? Thanks!

**This seems to happen when I try to save the children back to the DB. I.e. hitting next/prev should save whatever value users puts into the HTML input before moving on to the next Parent and pre-loading its children**

Answer (score 1):

If `parent` is a helper, then I don't think you can use the subscript notation to get its properties, at least not reactively. However you should be able to use this instead:

```handlebars
{{#with parent}}
  {{#each childrenArray}}
    <input {{attributes}}>
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

---

Update: The other thing that is probably required is to use an [attribute helper](http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Attribute-Helpers). I've also updated the code above to use this.

```
Template.yourTemplateName.helpers({
  attributes() {
    return {
      type: 'text',
      id: this.id,
      value: this.foo
    };
  }
});
```

---

Update 2:

Working "offline" in a git repo by the OP I realized that the modal body was better done as a separate template, such that the data context for that template would change reactively. The part of the code that was at odds is not represented in the question, so read this question and answer with a grain of salt.

Comment: ack..still getting same results. The html `value` simply isn't reactively changing. At this point I'm thinking it's just something internal, perhaps with it being inside the bootstrap modal

Comment: ah, yes, I think you need to create an attribute helper: http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Attribute-Helpers.

Comment: So `foo` is a property on the document. I'll have several inputs per property. I.e. `foo`, `bar`, etc.. that will be dynamic. So I just need to find a way to pass in the property name into the `attributes` helper as a param. 

Calling `{{attributes foo}}` to `attributes(param)` and then logging `param` prints `undefined`. It's almost as if you can't pass params to attribute helpers? Any idea?

Note: Writing helper as `attributes: function(property)` doesn't seem to work either

Comment: where is `foo` vs. `bar` coming from? meaning what decides whether you want to use foo vs. bar?

Comment: `foo` and `bar` will be hardcoded in the template. So in every iteration of `children`, a few `inputs` for some `properties` of the embedded doc will need to be rendered. Where the HTML `values` are pre-rendered with the values from the DB

Comment: well, then I guess you can just create as many `attribute` helpers as you wish and then choose the right one to use in the code.

Comment: oh man...it's still doing it. So here's what I realized. If I close the modal, and then reopen by clicking on a link to get to another Parent - the `values` are pre-populated correctly. So it's only when navigating through the parents while the modal is open, that the reactivity for the children doesn't work.

Comment: I think at this point we'd need to see a minimal code example to reproduce the issue in order to help. Do you have that?

Comment: I'll will put something together for you, I wish meteorpad still existed

Comment: I have https://jsfiddle.net/56yb3mqv/8/ so far that I forked from another Meteor fiddle. It's incomplete and I've only gotten so far as to show the `modal` popup and then display what would include some Parent.name. How can I go about adding the `Template`, `Helpers` and `Collection`. Or are Meteor `reprexes` best served by hosting project on a repo and having others clone to reproduce?

Comment: Please clone https://github.com/smohanty92/myapp and use test DB I put in ReadMe. You can see the strangeness going on

Comment: In a nutshell, problem seems to be that Blaze isn't reactively pre-populating `attributes` after a DB hit has been made to a parent (updating its children)

Comment: that's odd, because `parent` does appear in the template (in the `#with`), so Blaze knows that any changes to `parent` will require a recomputation of that sub-template.

Comment: I've tried every permuatation possible of getting children to show reactively. `with`, `each`, `each in`, `attributes` and getting `children` from a separate helper. I'm either blinded at this point and missing something stupid and obvious, or perhaps this is a bug with Meteor/Blaze

Comment: Typically, reactivity works best at the template level. You current have no template whose data context changes. So while I don't know why your current code (I ran it) doesn't work as expected, it would almost certainly work if you created a separate template `parent` and use it in the modal body and then change the data context for that template on prev/next.

Comment: I created a pull request for you with a fix. https://github.com/smohanty92/myapp/pull/1.

Comment: If only SO, had an option to buy a user coffee. This does work in my reprex but not my app yet. I'm gonna look into that soon. Rest assured, I'll accept your answer

Comment: btw, I wouldn't recommend working with Blaze anymore at this point. It's a nice framework, but React is the way to go now (in meteor). Broader use, more documentation, more actively developed. So if you are not yet too deep into your project, you could consider switching to React. You might have other issues there but not this one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, this project has 2+ years of development hell using Blaze. It's why this otherwise trivial issue has become such a pain to debug. Perhaps further down the line I can look into refactoring. 

But good to know. I'd definitely using React over Blaze fur any future Meteor Project.

Are you still using Meteor? If so, are you using it for your robotics projects or just for fun?

Comment: I am. I still don't know anything better for live data synchronization. And I've looked, believe me. I've recently described what I like about it here: https://insights.dice.com/2020/08/21/5-backend-javascript-frameworks-experts-love/.

Comment: Great article! I am surprised that you've found it to be the best for live data synchronization. I acknowledge its ease of setting up client-server apps from scratch and taking away a lot of the overhead, but I don't know how practical this is for production apps.

It'd be interesting to see how you're using it in your projects though

Comment: I'd be curious to see alternatives for data synchronization. I really don't know of any alternatives. Even if using GraphQL you'd still have to create the server-to-client pub/sub (push, rather than pull) yourself, no? Why would meteor not be practical for production? as long as you don't subscriber to more than you need it behaves much like any good-old express app.

Comment: I was alluding more to its general reputation for being outdated and unsupported. Also, that it's not used abundantly for large-scale apps. I'm not disagreeing on a technical sense, just perhaps swayed by the general opinion of it. I'd love to see how you're using it for ML!